# onActivityResult is not working in fragment

Tags: java, android

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_home, container, false);


        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton=(FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.picker);
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity() , Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    new MultiContactPicker.Builder(getActivity()) //Activity/fragment context
                            .hideScrollbar(false) //Optional - default: false
                            .showTrack(true) //Optional - default: true
                            .searchIconColor(Color.WHITE) //Optional - default: White
                            .setChoiceMode(MultiContactPicker.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE) //Optional - default: CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
                            .handleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity() , R.color.colorPrimary)) //Optional - default: Azure Blue
                            .bubbleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity() , R.color.colorPrimary)) //Optional - default: Azure Blue
                            .bubbleTextColor(Color.WHITE) //Optional - default: White
                            .showPickerForResult(CONTACT_PICKER_REQUEST);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Remember to go into settings and enable the contacts permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CONTACT_PICKER_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                List<ContactResult> results = MultiContactPicker.obtainResult(data);
                for (int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
                    ListItem listItem = new ListItem(
                            "Name:  "+results.get(i).getDisplayName(),
                            "Contact No: "+results.get(i).getPhoneNumbers()
                    );
                    listItems.add(listItem);
                }

                adapter = new MyRecycleAdapter(listItems,this.getActivity());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "MyTag"+results.get(0).getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("MyTag", results.get(0).getDisplayName());
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                System.out.println("User closed the picker without selecting items.");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I use this `onActivityResult` in fragment? Whenever I run this code at last "adapter is not connected" if this method is used as protected it works but in fragment does not support protected can anyone help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which `MultiContactPicker` you are using, but if it's this one: https://github.com/broakenmedia/MultiContactPicker, it looks like you can/should pass the fragment when you instantiate the `Builder`. So change this line:

```
new MultiContactPicker.Builder(getActivity())
```

to:

```
new MultiContactPicker.Builder(this)
```

Comment: bro i need to display data on recycler view but after selecting contacts it won't show contacts on recycler view when i use fragment.what should i do?

Comment: plzz help me if anyone want my code to try i can provide but plzz help me

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it was half of the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `super` in fragment's `onActivityResult`, remove this line:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

and override `onActivityResult` in your `Activity` and call `super` there:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**EDIT:**

After looking at your project I figured out the problem, it's a combination of the two answers you got. First in your `MainActivity` add `onActivityResult`, so your `MainActivity` will look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private viewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new viewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Then in your `FragmentHome` in the `floatingActionButton` `onClick` method change this line:

```
new MultiContactPicker.Builder(getActivity())
```

to this line:

```
new MultiContactPicker.Builder(FragmentHome.this)
```

And

```
  public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
      public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
          super(fragmentManager);
      }
  
      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          if(position == 0) return new FragmentHome();
          if(position == 1) return new FragmentRent();

          throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
      }
  
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return 2;
      }
  
      @Override
      public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
          if(position == 0) return "Home";
          if(position == 1) return "Rent";
        
          throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
      }
  }
```

And it will work, I tested it, the contact appears after that.

Comment: @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}                                                                                                                              -------------how should i use this in fragment this code works on activity but not in fragment ------------------------

Comment: bro i need to display data on recycler view but after selecting contacts it won't show contacts on recycler view when i use fragment.what should i do?

Comment: @VectorArora I showed how to use it in my answer. Remove this line `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)`, read my answer it's explained

Comment: no man itz not working can u have the code and try please.

Comment: @VectorArora can you confirm that `onActivityResult` in fragment is not called? Put a `Log` or a `Toast`.

Comment: ya it is not called i had used Log in that

Comment: @VectorArora so in your `MainActivity` you added the `onActivityResult` with `super` and in the fragment you removed the `super` line?

Comment: but wht abt the uper code floatingbutton

Comment: @VectorArora I'm not talking about floating button, in your `MainActivity` just override `onActivityResult` and put `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` and that's it. And in your fragment leave everything as it is but only delete the line `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)`

Comment: plz can u see the code once ??

Comment: @VectorArora ok

Comment: can i have ur facebook id?

Comment: @VectorArora you can post your code [here](https://pastebin.com), it's easier

Comment: wait ill give u github link is it ok to u?

Comment: @VectorArora sure

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tsaZlhOtdu74AK6fJdEAVu2WhMnjiKtr

Comment: please have a look on this and help me plss..

Comment: here is the MultipleContactPicker lib which i had integrated in project..     https://github.com/broakenmedia/MultiContactPicker

Comment: have you saw my app...plss

Comment: @VectorArora don't worry I'll take a look, I was away

Comment: please do it as soon as possible and tell me,,,,

Comment: @VectorArora you need to grant access

Comment: what and how should i do can u tell me? I had given contact permission to it...

Comment: @VectorArora I have no permission to access your Google Drive. Can you read my answer carefully and repeat what I mentioned there?

Comment: sorry dude i gave permission to access plzz check

Comment: @VectorArora The problem is resolved, check the edited answer